# ZF2 + Doctrine 2 - Entity created when requirements not met and values empty

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-validate

Extending on 2 previous questions about [form structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265665/zf2-doctrine2-fieldsets-not-validated-data-is-always-valid) and [validating collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45057551/zf2-doctrine2-fieldset-in-fieldset-of-a-collection-in-fieldset-does-not-vali) I've run into the next issue.

My form validates properly. Including included collections by way of Fieldsets. But the innermost Fieldset should not result in an Entity and a FK association to the parent if its values are not set.

An `Address` may or may not have linked `Coordinates`. It's possible to create all of these in the same Form.

However, the `Coordinates` should not be created and should not be linked from the `Address` if no coordinates have been given in the Form. They're not required in the Form and the Entity `Coordinates` itself requires both properties of Latitude and Longitude to be set.

Below, first the Entities. Following are the Fieldsets used for the `AddressForm`. I've removed stuff from both unrelated to the chain of `Address` -> `Coordinates`.

**`Address.php`**

```
class Address extends AbstractEntity
{
    // Properties

    /**
     * @var Coordinates
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Country\Entity\Coordinates", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER", orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="coordinates_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $coordinates;

    // Getters/Setters
}
```

**`Coordinates.php`**

```
class Coordinates extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="latitude", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $latitude;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="longitude", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $longitude;

    // Getters/Setters
}
```

As is seen in the Entities above. An `Address` has a `OneToOne` uni-directional relationship to `Coordinates`. The `Coordinates` entity requires both `latitude` and `longitude` properties, as seen with the `nullable=false`.

It's there that it goes wrong. If an `Address` is created, but no `Coordinates`'s properties are set in the form, it still creates a `Coordinates` Entity, but leaves the `latitude` and `longitude` properties empty, even though they're required.

So, in short:

- A `Coordinates` Entity is created where non should exist
- A link to `Coordinates` is created from `Address` where non should exist

Below the Fieldsets and InputFilters to clarify things further.

**`AddressFieldset.php`**

```
class AddressFieldset extends AbstractFieldset
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        // Other properties

        $this->add([
            'type' => CoordinatesFieldset::class,
            'required' => false,
            'name' => 'coordinates',
            'options' => [
                'use_as_base_fieldset' => false,
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

**`CoordinatesFieldset.php`**

```
class CoordinatesFieldset extends AbstractFieldset
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'latitude',
            'required' => true,
            'type' => Text::class,
            'options' => [
                'label' => _('Latitude'),
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'longitude',
            'required' => true,
            'type' => Text::class,
            'options' => [
                'label' => _('Longitude'),
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

**`AddressFieldsetInputFilter.php`**

```
class AddressFieldsetInputFilter extends AbstractFieldsetInputFilter
{
    /** @var CoordinatesFieldsetInputFilter $coordinatesFieldsetInputFilter */
    protected $coordinatesFieldsetInputFilter;

    public function __construct(
        CoordinatesFieldsetInputFilter $filter,
        EntityManager $objectManager,
        Translator $translator
    ) {
        $this->coordinatesFieldsetInputFilter = $filter;

        parent::__construct([
            'object_manager' => $objectManager,
            'object_repository' => $objectManager->getRepository(Address::class),
            'translator' => $translator,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Sets AddressFieldset Element validation
     */
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->add($this->coordinatesFieldsetInputFilter, 'coordinates');

        // Other filters/validators
    }
}
```

**`CoordinatesFieldsetInputFilter.php`**

```
class CoordinatesFieldsetInputFilter extends AbstractFieldsetInputFilter
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'latitude',
            'required' => true,
            'allow_empty' => true,
            'filters' => [
                ['name' => StringTrim::class],
                ['name' => StripTags::class],
            ],
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => StringLength::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'min' => 2,
                        'max' => 255,
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'name' => Callback::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'callback' => function($value, $context) {
                            //If longitude has a value, mark required
                            if(empty($context['longitude']) && strlen($value) > 0) {
                                $validatorChain = $this->getInputs()['longitude']->getValidatorChain();

                                $validatorChain->attach(new NotEmpty(['type' => NotEmpty::NULL]));
                                $this->getInputs()['longitude']->setValidatorChain($validatorChain);

                                return false;
                            }

                            return true;
                        },
                        'messages' => [
                            'callbackValue' => _('Longitude is required when setting Latitude. Give both or neither.'),
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        // Another, pretty much identical function for longitude (reverse some params and you're there...)
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Adding a DB Dump image. Shows empty latitude, longitude.

[image: Empty latitude/longitude]

**EDIT2:** When I remove `'allow_empty' => true,` from the `AddressFieldsetInputFilter` inputs and fill a single input (latitude or longitude), then it validates correctly, unless you leave both inputs empty, then it breaks off immediately to return that the input is required. (`Value is required and can't be empty`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By chance did I stumple upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27857034/1155833), which was for allowing a Fieldset to be empty but validate it if at least a single input was filled in.

By extending my own `AbstractFormInputFilter` and `AbstractFieldsetInputFilter` classes from an `AbstractInputFilter` class, which incorporates the answer, I'm now able to supply FielsetInputFilters, such as the `AddressFieldsetInputFilter`, with an additional `->setRequired(false)`. Which is then validated in the `AbstractInputFilter`, if it actually is empty.

The linked answer gives this code:

```
<?php
namespace Application\InputFilter;

use Zend\InputFilter as ZFI;

class InputFilter extends ZFI\InputFilter
{
    private $required = true;

    /**
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isRequired()
    {
        return $this->required;
    }

    /**
     * @param boolean $required
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setRequired($required)
    {
        $this->required = (bool) $required;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isValid()
    {
        if (!$this->isRequired() && empty(array_filter($this->getRawValues()))) {
            return true;
        }

        return parent::isValid();
    }
}
```

As I mentioned I used this code to extend my own `AbstractInputFilter`, allowing small changes in `*FieldsetInputFilterFactory` classes.

**`AddressFieldsetInputFilterFactory.php`**

```
class AddressFieldsetInputFilterFactory extends AbstractFieldsetInputFilterFactory
{
    /**
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface|ControllerManager $serviceLocator
     * @return InputFilter
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        parent::setupRequirements($serviceLocator, Address::class);

        /** @var CoordinatesFieldsetInputFilter $coordinatesFieldsetInputFilter */
        $coordinatesFieldsetInputFilter = $this->getServiceManager()->get('InputFilterManager')
            ->get(CoordinatesFieldsetInputFilter::class);
        $coordinatesFieldsetInputFilter->setRequired(false); // <-- Added option

        return new AddressFieldsetInputFilter(
            $coordinatesFieldsetInputFilter,
            $this->getEntityManager(),
            $this->getTranslator()
        );
    }
}
```

Might not be a good idea for everybody's projects, but it solves my problem of not always wanting to validate a Fieldset and it definitely solves the original issue of not creating an Entity with just an ID, as shown in the screenshot in the question.